# Getting "Invalid csrf token" message while requesting for http://www.sonyliv.com/api/v2/vod/search API in chrome postman

Tags: python, api, scrapy, postman

While requesting http://www.sonyliv.com/api/v2/vod/search API, I am getting "Invalid csrf token" message in chrome postman.

```
 {
    "code": "403",
    "name": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Invalid csrf token"
}
```

When I look to Chrome Inspect Element > Network tab in Headers section, I found

> "X-XSRF-TOKEN:tGXcHOmy-ro-GQfTestDSAp8EINq85dwHpdU"

as a token but this token is changed in every session, how can i pass X-XSRF-TOKEN value in my request to get the required result.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the CSRF tokens is that you can't call an API service if you're not doing it from the expected form, that's why it always changes its value.

I'm guessing you're trying to use that API not officially... so what you could try is to GET the base website and store in a cookie jar all the cookies it sends you and then try to query the search endpoint.

That way your request will include the XSRF token and the rest of the cookies and hopefully the server will think you request is legit.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am new to this, could you please help me resolving the issue. I am not theoretically understand the concept. Please help me.

Comment: Visit  http://www.sonyliv.com with chrome and using the Chrome inspector go to Aplication -> Cookies and you will see all the cookies the site sets, among them is the CSRF token you need to use to call the search API.

Then in postman add the header param with the right XSRF token value.

It could work, but if the CSRF system is well implemented probably will also check other header params like origin, and maybe it has some kind of custom validation

Comment: I tried as you said, I went to sonyliv.com then Application -> cookies and got XSRF-TOKEN: qnaSenns-pZauqPo6KMBiUZ33Q-Hb7ucEi24
but this also refresh dynamically. Also, I tried to pass this as a token but then i get below message in postman:
{
    "code": "40002",
    "name": "VOD Content Service :: Bad Request",
    "message": "Invalid search set"
}
Could you please help. Your help will be very supportable.

Comment: Well... you solved the CSRF issue that's a good first step and is what you were asking for. The CSRF tokens are valid for a single use always, so you'll need to refresh it for each search.
The new error you get is because the API seems to be expecting other param and you're not sending it.
Inspect the request with Chrome inspector and try to send all the parameters you can to make it look the same both in the URL as in the headers. Sorry I can't do it it could take you some time to figure it out, but I wish you best of lucks with it.